# store.getState() returning empty value in index.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

using nextjs for server-side-rendering trying to get the state from redux store in getServerSideProps(). but getting emtpy value.

getting data from redux in client side inside the component with `const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList) const { loading, error, products } = productList` works fine. but when using getServersideProps() im getting emtpy results.

index.js:

```
import store from '../redux/store'

export default function Home({products, error, loading}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Products loading={loading} error={error} products={products} />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const state = store.getState()
  const { loading, error, products } = state.productList

  return {props: {products: products, loading: loading, error: error}}
}
```

*note: even when i did `console.log(store.getState())` inside the component its still returning empy array

reducer:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST':
            return { loading: true, products: [] }
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS':
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload }
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL':
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

action:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST' })

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')

        dispatch({
            type: 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS',
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL',
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message : error.message
        })
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    categoryList: categoryListReducer,
})

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS, preload Redux data in getServerSideProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281070/nextjs-preload-redux-data-in-getserversideprops)

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work well for my case.

Answer (score 2):

try invoking getState() directly and don't forget to pass it as argument and also make sure you have passed the store to your app component

```
export async function getServerSideProps(getState) {
  const state = getState()
  const { loading, error, products } = state.productList

  return {props: {products: products, loading: loading, error: error}}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is `useDispatch` is a [React-Redux function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch), but the store has not been connected to the React components.

Instead of `useDispatch` try `store.dispatch` instead:

```
import store from '../redux/store'

export default function Home({products, error, loading}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(listProducts())
  })

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Note, the array passed to `useEffect` controls when that effect is run, so it would not make sense to pass in the dispatch function. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240526/useeffect-second-argument-variations-in-react-hook) for more details.

You could also connect the Redux store to the React components using React-Redux and keep using `useDispatch`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but the issue is gettiing the state in `getServerSideprops()` function in index.js.

Comment: The `useDispatch()` function is not putting anything into store, so `store.getState()` in `getServerSideprops()` will never return anything